# Adding HTML in Text Area. Text Area not showing value when inspect element

Tags: css, html

I write a text in text area box but what I write is not showing via inspect element. Please help I want it show what I write in text box when I inspect element it.

```
<div class="F0XO1GC-j-k">
  <label for="gwt-uid-4809"> Write an invitation message </label>
  <textarea class="gwt-TextArea F0XO1GC-Nb-g" rows="10" id="gwt-uid-4809" dir="ltr"></textarea>
  <div class="F0XO1GC-Nb-o" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></div>
  <div class="F0XO1GC-b-S F0XO1GC-Nb-f" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true"></div>
  <div class="F0XO1GC-b-Db"> The group's name, description, and address will automatically be included in the email. </div>
</div>
```

I expect it to show value when I inspect element it.

Answer (score 1):

Your expectations are wrong. This is normal behaviour.

The content of the textarea element is the **default** value of the field (used to initially populate the field and set its value when a `reset` button is activated).

The value you type into it is the **current** value.

The DOM inspector shows you the content, so it shows the default value.

When you submit the form, or read its `value` property with JavaScript, you will get the current value.

Comment: @DavidWilliams it is hard to tell what you are trying to ask here. Please go read [ask], and then edit your original question above accordingly. Right now I have not even the faintest idea of what problem you are actually trying to solve here, and I doubt anyone else has either.

Comment: If you want to add stuff to the value before submitting it, then you should forget about the DOM inspector entirely, and access the value property (as I said in the last sentence of this answer). That's a completely different problem to the one you asked about though, so you should ask a *new* question if you are still stuck.